# How to catch window.print() function call?

Tags: javascript

There's a way to check if somebody's printing the page at the moment by listening to 'print' changes:

```
const mql = window.matchMedia('print');
mql.addEventListener('change', e => {
  if (e.matches) console.log('Printing');
});
```

But this doesn't work if Print was called manually by window.print() function. Is there still a way to catch it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply overwrite the `print` function to one that does your bidding before calling the real print function:

```
{
    const realPrint = window.print;
    window.print = ()=>{
        console.log("printing");
        realPrint();
    }
}
```

(By using a `const` variable inside a block, we avoid leaking `realPrint` into the outer scope.)